# Error in Google Maps iOS Utils - No known instance method for selector didTapPOIWithPlaceID

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-ios-utils

I downloaded the Google Maps iOS Utils framework via pod install. Everything was fine and I was able to connect the functions I needed. But now at compilation it produces an error:

> No known instance method for selector mapView: didTapPOIWithPlaceID:
>   name: location

[image]

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

The error occurs in the framework itself.

Comment: does anyone has a fix for this ? I'm having the exact same isssue.